# Retrofit2 make API call for each item in response from API call data

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-livedata

I have a requirement, where I get a list of products from an API, but then need to make a seperate API call for each product to get their images. I've tried to handle it using a for loop and observing each data, but problem is that I only get 2 added images so I can't display the data. . My Fragment looks like this :

```
homeViewModel.getProducts()

homeViewModel.getProductMutableLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
        updateProducts(it)
    }
})

private fun updateProducts(products: GetNewProductResponse) {
    val images = ArrayList<String>()
    if(products.isNotEmpty()) {
        for(product in products){
            homeViewModel.getImageForProduct(product)
        }
        homeViewModel.getProductImageMutableLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            images.add(it)
            if(images.size == products.size){
                //display images
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And my viewmodel looks like this

```
 fun getProducts() {
    val url = Constants.NEW_BASE_URL

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val api: GetProductsAPIService = retrofit.create(GetProductsAPIService::class.java)
    val myCall: Call<GetNewProductResponse> = api.getProducts()

    myCall.enqueue(object : Callback<GetNewProductResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetNewProductResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("HomeViewModel", "Something went wrong", t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<GetNewProductResponse>,
            response: Response<GetNewProductResponse>
        ) {
            if(response.body() != null) {
                getProductMutableLiveData.postValue(response.body()!!)
            }
        }
    })
}
fun getImageForProduct(product: GetNewProductResponseItem){
    val url = Constants.NEW_BASE_URL

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val api: GetMediaAPIService = retrofit.create(GetMediaAPIService::class.java)
    val myCall: Call<GetMediaResponse> = api.getMedia("media/${product.featuredMedia}")

    myCall.enqueue(object : Callback<GetMediaResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetMediaResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("HomeViewModel", "Something went wrong", t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<GetMediaResponse>,
            response: Response<GetMediaResponse>
        ) {
            if(response.body() != null) {
                getProductImageMutableLiveData.postValue(response.body()!!.guid.rendered)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: can you explain what problem you are facing now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to observe data first

change

```
  if(products.isNotEmpty()) {
        for(product in products){
            homeViewModel.getImageForProduct(product)
        }
        homeViewModel.getProductImageMutableLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            images.add(it)
            if(images.size == products.size){
                //display images
            }
        })
    }
```

to

```
  if(products.isNotEmpty()) {
        homeViewModel.getProductImageMutableLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            images.add(it)
            if(images.size == products.size){
                //display images
            }
        })
        for(product in products){
            homeViewModel.getImageForProduct(product)
        }
    }
```